# Request recursive list of server files from client

Tags: python, smb, fileserver

I need to get a complete list of files in a folder and all its subfolders regularly (daily or weekly) to check for changes. The folder is located on a server that I access as a network share.
This folder currently contains about 250,000 subfolders and will continue to grow in the future.
I do not have any access to the server other than the ability to mount the filesystem R/W.

The way I currently retrieve the list of files is by using python's `os.walk()` function recursively on the folder. This is limited by the latency of the internet connection and currently takes about 4.5h to complete.

A faster way to do this would be to create a file server-side containing the whole list of files, then transfering this file to my computer.

Is there a way to request such a recursive listing of the files from the client side?

A python solution would be perfect, but I am open to other solutions as well.
My script is currently run on Windows, but will probably move to a Linux server in the future; an OS-agnostic solution would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided the answer to your question:

> I do not have any access to the server other than the ability to mount the filesystem R/W.

Nothing has to be added after that, since any server side processing requires the ability to (directly or indirectly) launch a process on the server.

If you can collaborate with the server admins, you could ask them to periodically start a server side script that would build a compressed archive (for example a zip file) containing the files you need, and move it in a specific location when done. Then you would only download that compressed archive saving a lot of network bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in multiple ways. I would do this by doing a running a script over ssh like

```
ssh xys@server 'bash -s' < local_script_togetfilenames.sh
```

If you prefer python you can run a similar python script by adding #!python assuming python is installed on the server

If you want to stick to fully python you should explore python RPC(Remote process call)
You can use rPyC library  . Documentation is
[here](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal, but I do not have SSH access to the server